# SSRS get number of weeks days hours and minutes from an int representing timespan in minutes

Tags: reporting-services

i have a value lets say its: 24544 I obtain this information from data set to populate the value of one of my columns.
i want to display it in my report as:

1. W: 2
2. D: 3
3. H: 1
4. M: 4

i've tried
`=Format(DateAdd("n", Fields!Downtime.Value, "00:00:00"), "wk:dd:HH:mm")` but it does not accept `ww` or `wk` and exceeds number of days above 7 (which should increase the counter of weeks instead). I work in VS 2010 How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these expressions in your placeholders.

W: `=FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080)`

D: `=FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - (FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)/1440)`

H:`=FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - ((FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)+ (FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - (FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)/1440))*1440))/60)`

M:`=Fields!Downtime.Value - (((FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080)*10080)+ (FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - (FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)/1440))*1440)+ (FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - ((FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)+(FLOOR((Fields!Downtime.Value - (FLOOR(Fields!Downtime.Value/10080))*10080)/1440))*1440))/60)*60))`